# Error While reading data From XML using JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

i have a xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<childrens>
<child entity_id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
<child entity_id="2" value="Apparel" parent_id="1">
    <child entity_id="4" value="Shirts" parent_id="2"/>
    <child entity_id="5" value="Pants" parent_id="2"/>
</child>
<child entity_id="3" value="Accessories" parent_id="1">
    <child entity_id="6" value="Handbags" parent_id="3"/>
    <child entity_id="7" value="Jewelry" parent_id="3"/>
</child>
</child>
</childrens>
```

n have tried to get data where parent_id=2 n have written this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('child').attr('[parent_id=3]').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
                    alert(id);

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

but it is not working

if i remove `.attr('[parent_id=3]')` then each id will be alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong use of `attr`, the way you used `attr('[parent_id=3]')` will search attributes with `name=[parent_id=3]` and if element has such attributes then it string value will be used by each which seems not required here.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uv23s/)**

Change

```
$(xml).find('child').attr('[parent_id=3]').each(function(){
```

To

```
$(xml).find('child[parent_id=3]').each(function(){
```